# Public key setup issue in windows environment for scp

Tags: hudson, scp

I am trying to configure a Hudson job to copy result of Hudson job (consists of multiple files) into a Hudson server for results consolidation from multiple slaves. My intention is to use scp. Unfortunately, I have difficulties setting up the SSH public key/private key in windows environment (both slave and Hudson server are windows environment). I cannot migrate to Linux because I am not the owner of those machines.

I use the following procedures to set up the SSH public/private keys.

1. Configure ssh server in Hudson machine by performing the following:

   - cd C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin
   - mkgroup -l >> ..\etc\group
   - mkpasswd -l >> ..\etc\passwd
   - mkpasswd -d -u test >> ..\etc\passwd (Note: test is the user id used for SSH)
   - Download cygintl-2.dll & cygwin1.dll from http://samanthahalfon.net/resources/cygwin_includes.zip. Copy those dll files to C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin. 
     You will need to replace cygwin1.dll.
   - cd C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\etc
   - ..\bin\chown test *
   - ..\bin\chmod 600 *
   - Edit C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\etc\sshd_config with the following configuration:

     - Port 22
     - Protocol 2
     - StrictModes no
     - PubKeyAuthentication yes
     - AuthorizedKeysFile /c/home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
     - PasswordAuthentication no
     - UserPrivilegeSeparation no
   - To start it as Windows service by executing: net start opensshd
2. Configure ssh public key in Hudson machine, so that the test automation script will not be prompted for password:

   - In slave machine, using "ssh-keygen -t dsa" command to create key pairs. 
     By default the key pairs (files: id_dsa & id_dsa.pub) will be generated to C:\Documents and Settings\test.ssh\
   - Using "scp id_dsa.pub test@XX.XX.XX.XX:.ssh/id_rsa_upload.pub" command to upload public key to Hudson Server. 
     i.e. scp id_dsa.pub test@XX.XX.XX.XX:.ssh/id_rsa_upload.pub
   - In Hudson server, go to directory C:\Program Files\OpenSSH.ssh, then execute "type id_rsa_upload.pub >>authorized_keys"
   - Exit and restart opensshd on Hudson server by executing "net stop opensshd" and "net start opensshd" now you can login ssh server without password.
   - In Hudson server, execute the following:

     - cd C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\
     - chown -R test .
     - chmod -R 700 .ssh
     - cd .ssh
     - chmod 600 authorized_keys
   - In slave machine, edit C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\etc\ssh_config. Specify "IdentityFile /c/home/test/id_dsa".
3. Test from your slave computer which SSH private key has been executed. In the slave machine, connect by executing:

   ssh test@XX.XX.XX.XX (IP is Hudson server's IP)

   Unfortunately, it still prompts for the pass phrase.

I looked into the following possibilities as workaround but the results are not positive:

a. shared drive in Hudson server mapped to a drive in slave machine - Hudson does not permit "copy result.html Y:"

b. sftp - it also requires public key

c. Found a proposed solution to overcome shared drive issue by using "copy result.html \XX.XX.XX.XX\test\" but I encountered access denied error as I have 
   no idea how to specify the user id and password using this method. Refer to: [Hudson continuous integration server: how to see Windows mapped directories that are visible to Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284561/hudson-continuous-integration-server-how-to-see-windows-mapped-directories-that)

d: I have also looked into Hudson's plugin for any potential solution but could not find anything suitable or have no idea on the plugin usage.

It would be great if someone can spot my mistake in public key setup or propose an alternative solution for me to copy multiple files into Hudson server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify what is wrong first -- server or client.

1. To verify server setup same key on any Linux/Mac client (which is much more transparent) and try to connect to the server.
2. To verify that ssh on your slave machine loads your dsa identity key try next:

   ssh -i c:/home/test/id_dsa -v test@XX.XX.XX.XX

where `-i` would tell ssh where to get key and `-v` enables verbose mode which can help you to identify the problem.